# How to sequentially run all the tasks per host in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am writing an Ansible playbook where I have 3 tomcat nodes. Now my script does lot of things like copying the release from nexus to application nodes, deploying it, starting tomcats etc.

What i want to achieve is to do this sequentially. For example the playbook should run for one host and when it gets completed, it should start for another host. My inventory looks like below and I am using group_vars as I have multiple environments like prod, preprod etc.

Can someone help.

[webserver]
tomcat1
tomcat2
tomcat3

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"The playbook should run for one host and when it gets completed, it should start for another host."***

A: Use [serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size). For example,

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: webserver
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [webserver] ***********************************

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [tomcat1] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "tomcat1"
}

PLAY [webserver] ***********************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************
ok: [tomcat2] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "tomcat2"
}

PLAY [webserver] ***********************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************
ok: [tomcat3] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "tomcat3"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************
tomcat1: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0   
tomcat2: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0   
tomcat3: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

---

See [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-to-build-your-inventory)

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[webserver]
tomcat1
tomcat2
tomcat3
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for the response. This is looking okay to me. Let me try that out and I will respond back on this thread.

I have one more query if you can help.
Is it possible to do some validation checks through Ansible?
In my playbook, I provide the release number as a command line argument which will be entered manually now what i mean is while deploying a release say 5.50.03 using this playbook, I want to make sure the release number is correct. Don't want to deploy the earlier versions to Production. Any ideas?